# this || that || whatever style syntax in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got jQuery code that looks like this:

```
var $selected = $('#mySelector');

if (!$selected.length) {
  $selected = $('#anotherSelector');

  if (!$selected.length) {
    // etc.
  }
}
```

Pretty ugly. I'd like to do something like this:

```
var $selected = $('#mySelector') || $('#anotherSelector') || etc.
```

But since jQuery returns a jQuery object even when a selector doesn't match, this syntax doesn't work. Is there an equivalent with jQuery objects (or maybe a selector)? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that you can simply combine the selectors?  `$('#mySelector, #alternateSelector')` will return both if they're both present, but will also return either one individually if only one exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best approach but you could write out a small function to help achieve this. [Live Example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/QnbQQ/)

HTML

```
<div class="asdf">ad</div>
<div class="asdf">ad</div>
<div class="asdf">ad</div>
<div class="asdf">ad</div>
<div class="asdf">ad</div>
```

JS

```
function test(selector){
    var list = $(selector);
    if (list.length > 0) return list;
    else return null;
}

console.log($('.asdfasdf') || $('.asdf'));
console.log(test('.asdfasdf') || test('.asdf'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could (ab)use the comma operator:

```
var $selected;
($selected = $('#mySelector'), $selected.length) ||
  ($selected = $('#anotherSelector'), $selected.length);
```

Comment: You *could*, but such eregious abuse shall be punished in hell.

Comment: @delnan: Honestly though, I haven't seen a better use for the comma operator than in situations like this.

Comment: while I cannot upvote your answer, since I am not an SME on Jquery, I can point out that love `(ab)use` as a verb.

Comment: @delnan: [Programmers Hell](http://everything2.com/title/Programmer+Hell) that is.

Comment: That's propably because the comma operator has little use, apart perhaps from plain old counting `for` loops (which are imho obsolete too) that "needs" to initialize or increment several variables at ones.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to my question, if you know you only ever want the first matching element (assuming that there's a possibility that both will exist) you can do something like this:

```
var $selected = $('#mySelector, #altSelector').slice(0,1);
```

That's going to limit the return result to only one element, which will be the first selector if present, the second if the first is missing and the second isn't, or an empty object if both are missing from the page.